# How to return all item in list of lists that are not in other list of lists in Python?

Tags: python, list

I have 2 list of lists:

```
list1: [[1,2,3],[2,5],[6,7,4]]
list2: [[1,3],[2],[6,4],[9,0,3]]
```

I want to do few things:

1. Find every number that is in list 1 but is not in list 2, store it in a new list, and then append this new list to list2.
   In our case: `new_list = [5,7]`
   and then, we will add it to `list2 = [[1,3],[2],[6,4],[9,0,3],[5,7]]`
2. Then, I want to remove duplicates of numbers from each list1 and list 2:
   In our case: `list1 = [[1,3],[2,5],[6,7,4]], list2 = [[1],[2],[6,4],[9,0,3],[5,7]]`

I have an implementation using For loops, but I need something more elegant for that.
Can you help me please find out a way?

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: Sorry - Python.

Answer (score 0):

Using Python, you can do the first part with a set comprehension:

```py
list2.append(list({i for j in list1 for i in j}.difference({i for j in list2 for i in j})))
```